Solution to recurrence equation $T(x,y) = T(x-1,y) + T(x,y-1) + O(1)$ in terms of big-O expression
What would be the solution, expressed in big-O notation, to the recurrence equation $$T(x,y) = T(x-1,y) + T(x,y-1) + O(1)$$ with base case being either or both $$T(x,0) \text{ for any x}$$ $$T(0,y) \text{ for any y}$$
It will be helpful if you can also explain in terms of moving from point $(x,y)$ to the left edge, bottom edge or origin in a lattice grid.

An example is $\binom{x+y}{x}$

Time Complexity of each $(x,y)$ node depends on its left neighbor $T(x-1,y)$ and bottom neighbor $T(x,y-1)$ and additional term $O(1)$. To compute $T(x,y)$, we need:

$T(x,y−1)$ which itself depends on $T(x, y-2), \dots, T(x, 0)$
$T(x-1,y)$ which itself depends on $T(x-2, y), \dots, T(0, y)$

The recurrence resembles the computation of paths in a grid, where the total work grows as the sum of dependencies across the entire grid. And due to our base case, This structure will mirror Pascal's triangle, where each entry is the sum of two entries above of it. ignoring the $O(1)$ term for simplicity :
$$\begin{aligned} \binom{x+y}{x} \sim \frac{2^{x+y}}{\sqrt{\pi \cdot x \cdot y}} \quad \text{(Stirling's approximation for factorials)}  \end{aligned}$$
(The $O(1)$ term contributes linearly to the total work over all cells but is negligible compared to the exponential growth of $\binom{x+y}{x}$, So the overall complexity is still governed by the binomial coefficient.)
